# Momentum educed gravity in a vacuum?

Tags: gravity, vacuum, space

I'm just curious about the movie "Interstellar" where they use this method of rapidly spinning the space station which would pull them outwards thus creating the illusion of gravity I was just wondering if that would even be plausible.

Somewhere in my mind I don't really think its possible because I feel its kind of like when you are on earth and you spin fast you can feel the blood move to your arms where I believe I've seen an astronaut in space showing that he doesn't get dizzy from spinning at a high rate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real life example from the early 70s. Although the video shows the man running around the walls of the station you can still see the effect of artificial gravity.

www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_p7LiyOUx0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153060)

Comment: I added a comment to tie the video to the artificial gravity subject showing a real example from almost 50 years ago.

Comment: related https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EHwT33YCAw

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=im-JM0f_J7s was after that video too thanks very helpful site :D